# What would have happened if Neville was the Chosen One?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter And The Order of the Phoneix*, Dumbledore tells Harry that two boys satisfied the prophecy - Harry himself and Neville Longbottom. However, the events of the book happen only because Voldemort chose Harry. What would have happened if Voldemort had chosen Neville? Could James and Lily be alive then? Or they would have suffered the fate of the Longbottoms i.e driven into madness?

Comment: [Interesting article somewhat related to this](http://www.beyondhogwarts.com/harry-potter/articles/neville-longbottom-the-other-chosen-one.html)

Comment: To be honest, I expect it would probably have been the same turn of events if Voldemort had chosen Neville, just with Harry's and Neville's situations reversed.  Haven't been able to find anything to contradict that.

Comment: @n.soong - Hardly. He would have been raised a wizard for starters.

Comment: I doubt if there could be a definite answer to this... Things would be *extremely* different, but still... Can't say for sure.

Comment: As Neville's parents were both Aurors -- I don't think Voldemort would have given his mum the chance to stand aside (or have had the chance to), so the events that lead to his curse backfiring could not have happened.